# Do you like Hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

I (and the other mods I hope) think this is a great opportunity for us to grow and get even more awesome content as we head towards gradumatation.

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Again, please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

Comment: I want a [sombrero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sombrero). I won't approve this motion unless mods get sombreros.

Comment: @Caleb: No good without [Mickey Mouse pants](http://bestofcalvinandhobbes.com/2012/05/being-cool-sombrero-mickey-mouse-pants/).

Comment: If you have specific issues/concerns with this promotion please share your concerns in the comments or in an answer. I'll address them as I see them or find someone who can.

Comment: Would the "_NO_" voters on this care to drop an answer or even a comment with a compelling reason why this should not happen? Remember you will be able to hide them from your personal site experience, but if there is any reason to avoid them for all visitors site-wide, this would be the time to state your case in an answer...

Comment: I too want a [sombrero](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13DvXLdr_H4) on my head, but only if it comes with authentic Argentian garb!

Comment: Heads up. I was going to lock this now as we've made the decision (but lock doesn't work for this IMO). However, if you'd like to raise a meta complaint/suggestion/comment please go ahead and open a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you guys were generally in favor of the idea, so we have replied to SE with an affirmative opt-in for our site. Expect your head topping options to show up for a couple weeks at the end of December.

For the record, the vote tally as of Nov 20th when we called it, this meta post was +13/-2, with no comments or answers giving any reasoning for the negative votes.

Comment: Did any site *not* want hats?

Answer (score 6):

I do, I do, I do like hats.

I hope it's not as generic as the rest of the site.  If it is, it won't be much fun!

Definitely need one of these:

[image: Priest Hat]

Comment: Make your own [St. Nicholas miter](http://www.stnicholascenter.org/pages/folding-miters/).